# Can I use an Enum construct in an EF add?

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework

I am using EF to do a simple insert of data into a table:

```
      var abc = new SampleSentence {
         WordFormId = wordForm.WordFormId,
         StatusId = 1, // Downloaded
         Text = ex
      });

      db.SampleSentences.Add(abc);
```

Here I set the StatusId to 1 in the code but I am wondering. I have a Status table that looks like this:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Status] (
    [StatusId] INT           NOT NULL,
    [Name]     NVARCHAR (50) NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [PK_Status] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([StatusId] ASC)
);

SELECT * FROM STATUS

StatusId   Name
1          Downloaded
```

Is there a way that I can specify in link that I want the StatusId to be equal to "Downloaded" by somehow joining in the db.Status into the definition of SampleSentence or is there some way in EF that I could have an Enum in my C# code?

Comment: Do you have a `Status` Model and `Statuses` DbSet? If yes then you can write something like

`StatusId = db.Statuses.Where(x=> x.StatusId == 1).Name`

Comment: First, you can use the enum datatype in the EF class model. Second, you can define a foreign key (and navigation property) from `SampleSentence` to `Status`.

Answer (score 0):

So you can go with...

```
  var abc = new SampleSentence {
     WordFormId = wordForm.WordFormId,
     StatusId = Convert.ToInt(WordFormId), // Downloaded
     Text = ex
  });

  db.SampleSentences.Add(abc);
```